# TypeScript how to use those generated classes?

Tags: angular, typescript

I created this piece of code. Task is simpe - I want to take input value on submit button click. But, all I get:

```
onSubmit() not defined.
```

How to do it? 
How to use those 3 ts files (app.module, main, app.component) from official tutorials? I know they generate some js files and I can include them manualy and just use them as is, but then why do I need these 3 files?

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {ShortCutService} from "./ShortCutService";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

@Component({
    selector: "content",
    template: `
            <div class="container">
                <a href="./user.html">User page</a>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div>
                    <input id="uriInput" type="text"/>
                </div>
                <button onclick="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
            </div>`,
    providers:[ShortCutService]
})
export class MainPageComponent
{
    constructor(private _shortcutService: ShortCutService) {

    }
    onSubmit() {
        alert("submit!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you handle an event in angular. The syntax is

```
(click)="onSubmit()"
```

Comment: So, basically, events now represents as (*eventthere*)="*js here*" ?